# Reseeding the Identity column for new records only (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data in a table, but am working on data loading. I want to reseed all new inserts for testing.

What would be the line to set all new inserts to a certain seed value?

Comment: you are using SQL Server aren't you?

Comment: I am. It is telling me that it cannot find the table.column name. But I'm querying the table with no problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For SQL Server use: [DBCC CHECKIDENT (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx)

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT 
( 
        table_name
        [ , { NORESEED | { RESEED [ , new_reseed_value ] } } ]
)
[ WITH NO_INFOMSGS ]
```

example:

```
USE YourDatabase;
GO
DBCC CHECKIDENT (YourTable, RESEED, 300);
GO
```

Comment: I don't need to have the column name given, just the table. works fine.
Cheers,